# Ternary relationship in database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

Suppose I want to model a system with employees and projects. Each employee can be part of 0 to n projects and a project can have 0 to n employees working on it. To model this I created 3 tables, `employee`, `project` and `work` with the following relations

| `employee` | (0..n) <----> (1..1) | `work` | (1..1) <----> (0..n) | `project` |

So far so good, table `work` has only two attributes (the id from the employee entry and the id from the project) and this works fine.

Each project must also have a public "chat" and a private one. The public allows everyone in the company to see and sent messages to the chat of that project. In the other hand, in the private one, only employees that are part of that particular project can see and send the messages.

The public chat comes easy to model, since everyone is allowed to see the messages. My doubt is about the private one. I want to force the condition of private messages into the database so as a private message is related to an employee that is part of that particular project. The way I found to do this is add an `id` to the table `work` and use this id as a foreign key in the `private_message` table. So the relationship between these two tables would be:

| `private_message` | (1..1) <----> (0..n) | `work` |

Is this a good way to model this situation? And if not, how could I improve this model?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you define `work`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you described, a message has a one to one relationship with the employee who created it and a one to one relationship with the project it belongs to. Given this, I would store those two relationships as part of the message itself and would model the `private_message` table as:

`id, employee_id, project_id, message, whatever other field you need`

You can then use your existing `work` table to determine which messages any individual employee should be able to see based on the projects they are assigned to using a query like the following:

```
SELECT private_message.*
FROM private_message
INNER JOIN
  (SELECT project_id
   FROM [work]
   WHERE employee_id = <employee_id of user you need messages for>) assigned_projects
         ON private_message.project_id = assigned_projects.project_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I would not do it that way.  I would keep the work table as you originally designed it, but add a field that concatonates the two ids.  I would then reference this field from the private_message table.

Adding an id field to work opens you up to duplicate records.

Comment: The duplicate record issue could be avoided by adding a unique constraint on `employee_id, project_id` in the `work` table.